# Tray icons disappears sometimes in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, system-tray

I upgraded system from 17.04 to 17.10. Sometimes after login to Gnome3 I dont see tray icons. And it looks like this:

[image]

Only standard Gnome applets are visible. After logout and login again it back to normal, like this:

[image]

Comment: Not really. I don't see any tray icons, Gnome and legacy icons either.

Comment: If the issue is resolved through logout-login, could you please try to reload Gnome Shell instead the next it happens? You can do that if you open its *Run* dialogue (Alt+F2), enter `r` and press Enter. Through the command `lg` you can also open *Looking Glass* which allows you to inspect the status and error log of all enabled Gnome Shell extensions.

Comment: Wow, I didn't knew that features. Thx for a tip. I will check it with `lg`

Comment: I made a reset of Gnome but it didn't help. Looking Glass didn't help, no errors. I will try to disable all extensions and try a reboot to see which cause problems.

Comment: Thanks @DavidFoerster. On my Gnome I used `journalctl -xe | grep Extension` to find culprit extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem was in old Unity `indicator-application`. Because I used Unity earlier in 17.04 and upgraded to 17.10 this indicator wasn't removed. I still have Unity available. After disabling `indicator-application` from autostart now legacy tray icons works fine. To disable autostart of this indicator remove `/etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop` file from system. Now it works with standard `Ubuntu Appindicators` Gnome extension.

Comment: after deleting that file, Should I run any command to open it again?

Comment: What you want to open?

Comment: I meant seeing my icons again as it was before upgrade, I fixed this by installing "TopIcons GNOME Shell Extension" now I have all icons at the top bar, Thanks dude

Comment: I installed this extension too but it is not updating any changes to tray icons if you still have Unity indicator-application. For example run Steam client or keepassxc with tray icon enabled and will not see icon in tray area. After restarting gnome-shell it will be but you need to restart gnome-shell to see changes made to tray.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is caused by an old Unity app-indicator which is in the system autostart. Remove it with `sudo apt remove indicator-application` and reboot.

Only removing the config setting `/etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop` as suggested in the another answer is not very clean and may cause issues later on.