# 18.04: Appindicators disappear after every reboot

Tags: gnome, 18.04, startup

I have a GTX970 and i7-3770. I upgraded Ubuntu to 18.04 from 16.04. Now I have the problem that appindicators disappear every time I startup my system, reboot, or even when the PC goes back from sleep.

To solve the issue, I need to restart Gnome shell every time this happens (press Alt+F2 and type r).

I already tried to remove the .gnome-shell folders, but the problem is still there.

How can I solve this without restarting Gnome shell every time? The command I do is the same, I press Alt+F2 and then I type r, that is doing exactly that command. Of course, restarting gnome shell makes the indicators reappear, but I want that they don't disappear, and want to understand why this happens.

What I tried:

```
Installing topicons extensions.
Removing gnome folders on my local share.
```

but nothing is working. Every time I use my PC I need to restart Gnome shell, and it's starting to be annoying.

The command I do is the same, I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and then I type <kbd>r</kbd>, that is doing exactly that command. Of course, restarting gnome shell make the indicators reappear, but I want that they don't disappear, and want to understand why this happens.

I have the topicons extension, but icons like skype or telegram are not loaded by this extension. They are loaded by some weird extensions included in ubuntu. I see there is 'ubuntu appindicators' extension, that is currently disabled by default, but the "ubuntu dock" is disabled too, and is currently working. So maybe there is some extensions conflict caused by some Ubuntu settings?

If i remove the gnome shell folders (with extensions etc), my desktop turn to default, and i still have the extensions dock and appindicators disabled and working.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**: I noticed that i have the same problem on another PC that has an i7-3770 too, but a gt430 gpu.
I really don't know if is a driver-related problem, but i have done the upgrade from 16 to 18.04 on this pc too, and i have the top icons like skype or telegram that disappear. I don't have this problem for icons like dropbox, diodon, or dreamweaver. I think these icons are 2 different types called by different extensions/widget.

UPDATE2:
I have the "Ubuntu appindicators" extension. That is disabled by default, i don't see any change by enabling it.
Is maybe the default ubuntu appindicator extension bugged?
I have the same problem with the dock extension, but this is working without problems.

**New update: Isnt there any folder that can i delete? I tried with a new user and it works.**

Update: Solution:
[Tray icons disappears sometimes in Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969138/tray-icons-disappears-sometimes-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: Which are the exact icon you see keeping disappearing? DropBox maybe?

Comment: Every icon. I mean the whole appindicator  extensions. So Skype, telegram, steam, teamviewer, etc.

Comment: O.k. that's weird, but I do not think it is related to the GPU or its drivers. I have the same happening to me too, but only for DropBox and Insync, using TopiconsPlus Extension as well because Gnome 3.28 has no try itself anymore. As for Steam and Teamviewer I cant reproduce this. But as well know no really culprit here otherwise I would have submitted a bug-report already.

Comment: I have the topicons extension, but icons like skype or telegram are not loaded by this extension. They are loaded by some weird extensions included in ubuntu. I see there is 'ubuntu appindicators' extension, that is currently disabled by default, but the "ubuntu dock" is disabled too, and is currently working. So maybe there is some extensions conflict caused bu some Ubuntu settings?

Comment: You can try the Intel iGPU using `prime-select intel` and rebooting. I find it easier to use than my GTX970.

Comment: Sorry but i need to use my GPU.

Comment: I have an nvidia GPU because i need it and i use it, i can't just switch to intel and rebooting.

Comment: Still up Still up Still up Still up Still up Still up

Comment: Here is the answer.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/969138/tray-icons-disappears-sometimes-in-ubuntu-17-10

Answer (score 9):

The issue is caused by an old Unity app-indicator which is in the system autostart.
Remove it with `sudo apt remove indicator-application` and reboot.
A [related post on Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969138/tray-icons-disappears-sometimes-in-ubuntu-17-10) suggested just to delete the autostart file, but I think it's better to do a clean uninstall.

Comment: After several other methods, this single command solved the problem for me.