# After suspend task manager items disappear Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: suspend, 18.04, gnome-shell, taskbar

I just found an issue with latest version of Ubuntu 18.04 with Lenovo legion y520. After lid is closed and opened, the task bar(right of notification bar on top) icons disappear. That is the running items icons showing on the notification bar. I can get back this only after restarting the system.

1. After lid closed (after suspend):
   [image: Screenshot of no icons on task bar]
2. After restarting: You can see the icons of Skype and slack which disappeared in image 1
   [image: After restarting, icons came back]

Any fixes?

Answer (score 3):

Those icons are provided by the "Ubuntu appindicators" GNOME extension (`gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`). As per GNOME's design/security policy all the extensions get disabled at lockscreen/suspend and restart after the user logs back in. It seems in your case somehow the extension is not getting reloaded.

When you find the icons missing, restart GNOME shell by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>, then typing `r` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> (note: this does *not* work in a Wayland session). This should bring back the icons.

Comment: This brings the icons back; but is there some way to fix the problem itself?

Comment: @SamWilson Consider reporting a bug against the Ubuntu appindicators package.

Comment: This bug seems to pretty much match: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/+bug/1740600 (oh, and the package is called `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`; there's nothing called just `appindicators`).

Comment: @SamWilson Yeah, that's mentioned in the first sentence of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 18.10. I tried the solution suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1067237/863921) and it seems to be working.

> The issue is caused by an old Unity app-indicator which is in the system autostart. Remove it with `sudo apt remove indicator-application` and reboot.